# Using Notepad++ find and replace with regular expression

Tags: html, regex, notepad++, calibre

I have a html menu file, which contains list of html pages, extracted by chm decoder.

```
(7,0,"Icons Used in This Book","final/pref04.html");
(8,0,"Command Syntax Conventions","final/pref05.html");
(9,0,"Introduction","final/pref06.html");
(10,0,"Part I: Introduction and Overview of Service","final/part01.html");
(11,10,"Chapter 1. Overview","final/ch01.html");
(12,11,"Technology Motivation","final/ch01lev1sec1.html");
```

I want create from this a 'table of contents' file for Calibre (HTML file that contains links to all the other files in the desired order). The final file should look like this:

```
<a href="final/pref04.html">Icons Used in This Book</a><br/>
<a href="final/pref05.html">Command Syntax Conventions</a><br/>
.
.
.
```

So first I need to remove the digit prefixes with regular expression, then add `a href` attribute to make hyperlink, and change the URL and title position. Can anyone show how to make this with Notepad++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would do it for you, I'm mac based so I don't have notepad++ but this works in dreamweaver. Presuming each expression is one line based.

Find:

```
\(.*?"(.*?)","(.*?)".*
```

Replace:

```
<a href="$2">$1</a><br/>
```

File:

```
(7,0,"Icons Used in This Book","final/pref04.html");
(8,0,"Command Syntax Conventions","final/pref05.html");
(9,0,"Introduction","final/pref06.html");
(10,0,"Part I: Introduction and Overview of Service","final/part01.html");
(11,10,"Chapter 1. Overview","final/ch01.html");
(12,11,"Technology Motivation","final/ch01lev1sec1.html");
```

After Replace All:

```
<a href="final/pref04.html">Icons Used in This Book</a><br/>
<a href="final/pref05.html">Command Syntax Conventions</a><br/>
<a href="final/pref06.html">Introduction</a><br/>
<a href="final/part01.html">Part I: Introduction and Overview of Service</a><br/>
<a href="final/ch01.html">Chapter 1. Overview</a><br/>
<a href="final/ch01lev1sec1.html">Technology Motivation</a><br/>
```

If it isn't one line based change `.*` to `.*?\n`. That should make it stop after each newline. For readability you also may want to add a newline to the replace.

Should probably explain the regex as well in case you want to modify it...

The first `\` is escaping the `(` so the regex knows to look for the literal character and the not special regex grouping. The `*?` says find every character until the first `"`; (`.` is any single character, `*` is zero or more occurrences of the preceding character, and `?` tells it to stop at the first occurrence of the next character, `"`). The last `.*` says keep going with the search. The `(` and `)` around the `.*?` group the found value into the `$1` and `$2`. The number correlates to the order in which it is in the regex.